# Finding a recent most duplicate records from SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

I want to find the recent duplicate records from SQL Server 2012. Here is the table structure I have.

I have table name called UserRegistration which contains the duplicate of UserID(GUID) and in same table, I have CreatedDate Column as well (Date). Now I want to find the recent duplicate records from this table.

Here is the same data.

```
id  FirstName  LastName  CreatedDate  UserID
109 FirstNameA  LastNameA 28-04-2015  GUID1
110 FirstNameC  LastNameD 19-05-2015  GUID2
111 FirstNameE  LastNameF 22-05-2015  GUID1
```

If you notice on above tables, GUID 1 are having the duplicate, Now I want to find the recent one means it should return me only those rows with duplication but recent data. So in above table structure, it should return me 111 because record has been created recently compared to the 109. I believe you understand.

Do let me know if you have any question. I am happy to answer. Thanks. Awaiting for the reply.

Harshal

Comment: As you see from the answers, your question is a bit ambiguous. In case of three matches for one userid, do you want to show the latest record only or all records except the first one?

Comment: @Harshal - did any of the solutions provided here helped you ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query this should do the work based on your i/p data -

```
create table #UserRegistration (id  int,FirstName  varchar(20),LastName  varchar(20),CreatedDate  date,UserID varchar(20))
insert into #UserRegistration
select 109, 'FirstNameA',  'LastNameA', '2015-04-28',  'GUID1' union
select 110, 'FirstNameC',  'LastNameD', '2015-05-19',  'GUID2' union
select 111, 'FirstNameE',  'LastNameF', '2015-05-22',  'GUID1'
select id,  FirstName,  LastName,  CreatedDate,  UserID from
(SELECT ur.*,row_number() over(partition by UserID order by CreatedDate) rn
FROM #UserRegistration ur) A
where rn > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Group your records by `UserID` and give your particular row a *rank* ordered by `CreatedDate`.

```
insert into tab(id, FirstName, LastName, CreatedDate, UserID) 
values(109, 'FirstNameA', 'LastNameA', '2015-04-28', 'guid1'),
      (110, 'FirstNameC', 'LastNameD', '2015-05-19', 'guid2'),
      (111, 'FirstNameE', 'LastNameF', '2015-05-22', 'guid1');

with cte as
(
  select id, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by UserID order by CreatedDate asc) as [Rank],
         FirstName, LastName, CreatedDate, UserID
  from tab
)
select id, FirstName, LastName, CreatedDate, UserID from cte where Rank > 1
```

`Rank > 1` condition is responsible for retrieving duplicated items.

sqlfiddle link:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4d1f2/6

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using tmp-tables:

```
SELECT  a.UserID,
        MAX(a.CreatedDate) As CreatedDate
INTO #latest 
FROM <your table> a
GROUP BY a.UserID
HAVING COUNT(a.UserID) > 1

SELECT b.id
FROM #latest a
INNER JOIN <your table> b ON a.UserID = b.UserID AND a.CreatedDate = b.CreatedDate
```

Comment: Thanks Tobyplz, I tried but getting an error saying - Invalid column name 'CreatedDate' on a.CreatedDate and mostly I tried to run without it which returns me total 460 records and when I ran this script it returns me 186 records, here is the query. ---select userId,COUNT (*) as morevalues from userregistration Group by userid having COUNT(*)>1

Comment: Wierd, I had no problems running this. Are you sure that the column name is spelled right?

Comment: @HarshalChoksi please mark as answer if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You'd rank your records with `ROW_NUMBER()` to give all last records per userid #1. With `COUNT()` you make sure only to get the userids having more than one record.

```
select
  id, firstname, lastname, createddate, userid
from
(
  select
    id, firstname, lastname, createddate, userid,
    row_number() over (partition by userid oder by createddate desc) as rn,
    count(*) over (partition by userid) as cnt
  from userregistration 
) ranked
where rn = 1 -- only last one
and cnt > 1; -- but only if there is more than one record for the userid
```

This gets the latest record for every userid that has duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten. It works awesome. :) Simply superb!

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
SELECT * FROM TableName tt WHERE 
exists(select MAX(createdDate) 
from TableName
where tt.UserID = UserID 
group by UserID 
having MAX(createdDate)= tt.createdDate)
```

I think your createddate field is not a date field, then try [Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/hh213505(v=sql.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
    WITH TempAns (id,UserID,duplicateRecordCount)
    AS
    (
        SELECT id,
        UserID, 
        ROW_NUMBER()OVER(partition by UserID ORDER BY id)
         AS duplicateRecordCount
        FROM #t
    )
    select * from #t where id in (
           select max(id )
           from TempAns
           where duplicateRecordCount > 1
           group by name )
```